# Android LambdaJ - unable to use, exception on every call

Tags: java, android, exception, lambdaj

I'm using lambdaj 2.4 with dependencies. My code (very simple):

```
 List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
                    new Person(13,"Steve",22,"London, UK"),
                    new Person(25,"Greg",28,"New York, USA"),
                    new Person(5,"Emily",22,"Bali, Indonesia"),
                    new Person(9,"Malih",14,"Jakarta, Indonesia"));

            List<String> personNames = extract(persons, on(Person.class).getName());
            System.out.println("personNames: "+personNames);
```

But it does not work, exception is:

```
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createEnhancer(ProxyUtil.java:89)
            at ch.lambdaj.proxy.ProxyUtil.createProxy(ProxyUtil.java:49)
            at ch.lambdaj.function.argument.ArgumentsFactory.createPlaceholder(ArgumentsFactory.java:68)
```

Any ideas how to make it working on Android?

Comment: have you checked line 89 of ProxyUtil ? This is very little and vague information, can you  provide more?

Comment: Nothing interesting there, only new Enchancer object creation, I can see it from decompiled code

Answer (score 2):

If you have the choice, you should consider using Retro Lambda. It's a backport of the full Java 8 Lambda Expression syntax for JDK 6 & 7 - and offers full, real closures (LambdaJ was pretty good alternative in the absence of language level support).

- [Retro Lambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda)
- [Retro Lambda Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda)
- [Stream Support - backport of Streams](http://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/)
- Blog post on setting up [RetroLambda for Android Studio](http://coscolla.net/retrolambda-android-studio/)

Comment: Tried retrolambda, result: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1, no t tried gradle plugin setup yet

Comment: Added a link on getting started - also this video on setting up Android with Lambda's and RxJava might be worth watching - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l63V5bZaS70.

Comment: Thanks for that. It looks contrived for me... so I need consider if I even really need lambdas in my case